# load different Layout component for Mobile and Desktop device on Blazor Server Application

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

I am developing a web application in Blazor Server that has different pages for mobile devices and desktop devices, so I can't just rely on CSS properties to differentiate page rendering. I would like that "App.razor" loads the correct layout depending on whether the user starts application from a mobile device or a desktop device. Is it possible? If so, how can I do?

Comment: Assuming you have a methodology to differentiate mobile and desktop devices (there's more than one), there's an article here I've written on how to implement dynamic layouts which should point you in the right direction. - https://shauncurtis.github.io/articles/A-Flexible-App.html

Comment: Thanks MrC aka Shaun Curtis. Your project is really very interesting and useful. In my case, however, the solution was even simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is very simple:
In the App.razor

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            @if (isMobile)
            {
                <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" defaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayoutMobile)" />
            }
            else
            {
                <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
            }
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there is nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>

@code
{
    [Inject] protected IJSRuntime _JS { get; set; }
    protected bool isMobile = false;

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            int innerWidth = await BrowserService.GetInnerWidth(_JS);

            if (innerWidth < 480)
               isMobile = true;
           else
               isMobile = false;

       }
    }
}
```

Where BrowserService is a service registered in Startup class:

```
public class BrowserService
{
    public static async Task<int> GetInnerWidth(IJSRuntime _JS)
    {
        return await _JS.InvokeAsync<int>("browser.getInnerWidth");
    }
}
```

and javascritp file:

```
window.browser = {

getInnerWidth: function () {
    return window.innerWidth;
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution does not work for me, because when the root page is first loaded the GetDimensions is not called. If I click on a different page then the solution works. What is wrong?

Comment: @Marc for information, there is a perfet nugget package for this : https://github.com/EdCharbeneau/BlazorSize